# Window.showModalDialog() using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am opening a child window using window.showModalDialog() method. 
In the child page i have few server side controls whenever a postback happens the child page opens in a new window.

I have also set in my head tag,but it is not working.

```
<base target ="_self/>
```

For example 
In Page 1: i have an anchor on whose click  i open a child page(page2).
In my child page Page2: I have an asp.net button to search based on the criteria. when i enter the criteria and click search, the search results are show in new window rather then the same window.

similar to the post
http://forums.asp.net/p/1246676/2297583.aspx

Comment: What is your question? Try and describe what you're trying to do in detail, show some of the code involved and any scripting errors you might be receiving.

Comment: Window.showDialog() is a Winforms Method and does not work in ASP.Net

Answer (score 1):

If you want to open child window in new window then you need to add

```
< base target="_blank" /> instead of < base target="_self" />
```

which opens `ModelDialog` in parent window.

Hope this clarifies your question.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you are wanting since you are not asking a question, but I think you want to use Javascript's Alert() method to get a messagebox like what the Window.ShowDialog() method does.

Comment: It's `alert()` not `Alert()`.